# Building Out SQL Value Subsets Based On Existing Table Data In One Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to build a temporary table based on values in #temp.

When I call this query on #temp:

```
SELECT  MarketID,
        SelectionID,
        LTP,
        SUM(LTV) AS LTVSum

FROM #Temp

WHERE MarketID = 116204134 
  AND SelectionID = 7610361
  AND [Timestamp] < '12:04:12.820'

GROUP BY MarketID, SelectionID, LTP
ORDER BY LTP DESC
```

I get this:

```
MarketID     SelectionID    LTP     LTVSum
116204134    7610361        2.80    44.44
116204134    7610361        2.78    268.98
116204134    7610361        2.76    301.70
116204134    7610361        2.74    1471.24
116204134    7610361        2.72    1928.14
```

Perfect - this the subset of data I need to go into the new #prices table for every combined `[MarketID]`, `[SelectionID]`, and `[Timestamp]` that exists in #temp.

The important bit is the `WHERE [Timestamp] < X` (where X is the current Timestamp being looked at)

Therefore, for each `[MarketID]`, `[SelectionID]`, `[Timestamp]` combination, there could be anywhere from 3 to 25 new rows going into #prices.

How would I build this #prices table for each and every combination in #temp?

Comment: Sounds like you would need a cursor

Comment: Is there some reason it's not simply removing the MarketID and SelectionID filters from the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT t.MarketID, t.SelectionID, t.[Timestamp], base.LTP,
        SUM(base.LTV) AS LTVSum
FROM #Temp t
LEFT OUTER JOIN [BaseTable] base on base.MarketID = tmp.MarketID
  AND base.SelectionID = tmp.SelectionID
  AND base.[Timestamp] < tmp.[TimeStamp]
GROUP BY t.MarketID, t.SelectionID, t.[Timestamp], base.LTP
ORDER BY base.LTP DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description of the question, it should simply be this:

```
SELECT  MarketID,
        SelectionID,
        LTP,
        SUM(LTV) AS LTVSum
INTO #prices
FROM #temp
WHERE [Timestamp] < '12:04:12.820'

GROUP BY MarketID, SelectionID, LTP
```